# The fullcalendar plugin doesn't render on some remote devices

Tags: fullcalendar

I am developing a scheduling web app for my company. The app will live on a server in our datacenter and will let users access the app from their devices. However, the fullcalendar plugin does not render the calendar on some devices.

Desktops seem to work well but on laptops the page renders and the calendar's top bar with the 'next/previous' and view buttons are visible but the calendar grid does not render at all.

The error is visible from the console as is as follows:

'Uncaught TypeError: E[r.substring(...)] is not a function fullcalendar.js:2
at f(fullcalendar.js:2)...

Any help is quite welcome...

[fullcalendar error on remote devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVnJm.png)

Comment: "Desktops seem to work well but on laptops"...unless they are actually running different software (e.g. different operating systems and browser versions), there is no specific difference between laptop and desktop, as far as web pages are concerned. You also talk about "remote" devices...are these devices connecting from outside your LAN or something? It's unclear. Maybe some script file is load downloading properly on that connection. Watch the Network tab (instead of Console) when the page is first loading, and see if any files fail to load properly.

Comment: Without further, more specific info (including OS/browser version numbers, fullCalendar versions, and relevant code samples) then it's hard to suggest anything more detailed.